# Search photo & videos from facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can we search public photos & videos from facebook by tags as input perameter as we do in flickr using the tags we search photos and flickr API returns list of photos.

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks
Gaurav

Answer (score 0):

last time I checked, photos uploaded to Facebook do not have tags. Therefore, it isn't possible to return photos that match a tag. What you could do, is search for groups or apps on Facebook and then retrieve the public photos there.

The search URL format is https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAHwKSuFoX7OpcyCezYGO1JkVzBaQq6fBdXoHPayxZCxta4EZC0fYSLPjO16Yf9FKOAkhOHrU2ROZCZB9fcbLsDtPFgy67dK5TXOeYJqG, where q is your query. More info can be found here. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an app that allows you to [search facebook photos](http://www.searchfacebookphotos.com)!

Answer (score 0):

The below api query will return everything that has that object_id tagged.

> https://graph.facebook.com/[object_id]/tagged

An example of this would be looking for everything tagging Heat Ultra Lounge (a project I'm working on). To get the objects tagged with this tag, I would use the below get address and include &access_token=[my or my app's access token]. Like so:

> https://graph.facebook.com/118613151504271/tagged?access_token=[youraccesstoken]